# What triggers an early session timeout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. When the application is left for a few minutes (about 15 minutes), the session times out and I can't access session values anymore.

However in my `web.config` file, I have the following line of code:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
```

So you would expect the session to time out after 30 minutes, sadly that's not happening. If I reduce the session to 5 minutes, then the session times out in 5 minutes, but with a bigger value like 30 minutes, it times out way too early.

What events or circumstances could trigger an early session timeout?

Comment: You're using InProc session state, so the it becomes the responsibility of the application pool to keep the session in-memory. Is the application pool recycled? Are you running a load balanced environment where you may be sent to another server/process after a few minutes?

Comment: You may need to set Idle Timeout setting for an Application Pool. Default time is 20 min

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set session timeout more than 20 min.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725925/how-to-set-session-timeout-more-than-20-min)

Comment: Are you sure the session is timing out?  This behaviour could be caused by your browser ditching the sessionid cookie (if you've got some aggressive cookie management software), or by the app domain being reloaded.  To prove if the session is actually ending early, try placing some logging in the Session_OnEnd event to see if you can determine more information about what is happening (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx).

Comment: @sisve is there a setting which causes the app pool to be recycled regularly? no i am not running in an environment which involves other servers

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that both the Server Side and the Client Side have the right timeout value. If your Client Side is set to 30 and your Server-Side is not set to anything, it will default to 20 min (I think 20 min is the timeout). Anything more than this and you may want to look at a different design pattern. If you really need to extend it, then both ends need to be configured with the extended timeout.